# Code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND', Require stack: [ ] error

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am setting up a project. I have made config folder for webpack and have installed all the required packages using `npm i`

I using node version 18.18.0 (npm v9.8.1).

My file structure is:

```
├── ├── config
│   ├── webpack.common.js
│   ├── webpack.dev.js
│   └── webpack.prod.js
├── kendo-ui-license.txt
├── NodeJsApi
│   ├── config.js
│   ├── controllers
│   ├── gulpfile.js
│   ├── helpers
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── package-lock.json
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── route.js
│   └── server.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── App.js
    ├── bootstrap.js
    ├── index.css
    ├── index.js
    ├── pages
    └── router.js
```

`webpack.dev.js` file:

```
const path = require("path"); //Path package co../Shared/Configonst webpack = require("webpack");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const APP_CONFIG = require("./../NodeJsApi/config");  // ignore this one
let HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let modifyResponse = require("node-http-proxy-json");

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const client_setting = 'AMX';

let fs = require("fs");
let key = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../certificates/", APP_CONFIG.CERTIFICATE.KEY));
let crt = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "../certificates/", APP_CONFIG.CERTIFICATE.CERT));
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: "./src/main.js"
    },
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "cheap-module-source-map",
    performance: {
        hints: false,
        maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
        maxAssetSize: 512000
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].[contenthash].js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")
    },
    devServer: {
        host: APP_CONFIG.WEB_APP_HOST,
        port: APP_CONFIG.WEB_APP_PORT,
        static: {
            directory: path.resolve(__dirname, "public")
        },
        hot: true,
        client: false,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        allowedHosts: "all",
        headers: {
            "X-Frame-Options": "deny"
        },
        server: {
            type: "https",
            options: {
                cert: crt, key: key
            }
        },
        
        compress: true
    },

    plugins: [
        new CompressionPlugin({
            algorithm: "gzip",
            test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
            threshold: 10240,
            minRatio: 0.8
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[/\\]locale$/, /en|es|pt|fr|ar/),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),

        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            jquery: "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery",
            "jquery-migrate": "jquery-migrate",
            "bootstrap": "bootstrap",
            "moment": "moment"
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/browser-support.html",
            filename: "./browser-support.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "style.css"
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "APP_CONFIG": JSON.stringify(APP_CONFIG),
            "CLIENT_SETTING": client_setting
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js/,
                resolve: {
                    fullySpecified: false
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "Shared"),
                    path.resolve(__dirname, "API")
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "eslint-loader",

                options: {
                    configFile: ".eslintrc.json",
                    outputReport: {
                        filePath: "eslint-report.html",
                        formatter: require("eslint-detailed-reporter")
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    {
                        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        options: {
                            esModule: false,
                        },
                    },
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|ico)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: "url-loader",
                    options: {
                        name: "Images\[name].[ext]"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "file-loader"
                }
            }

        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".css"],
        alias: {
            kendoCommonBootstrap: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/css/web/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css"),
            kendoBootstrap: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/css/web/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"),
            kendoBootstrapMobile: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/css/web/kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css"),
            bootstrapDateRangePickerJS: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"),
            bootstrapDateRangePickerCSS: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap-daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"),
            slimScrollJS: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"),
            kendoGrid: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.grid.min.js"),
            kendoChart: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/dataviz/chart/chart.min.js"),
            kendoTabStrip: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.tabstrip.min.js"),
            kendoTreeView: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.treeview.min.js"),
            kendoDatePicker: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.datepicker.min.js"),
            kendoDateTimePicker: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.datetimepicker.min.js"),
            kendoDropDownList: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.dropdownlist.min.js"),
            kendoMultiselect: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.multiselect.min.js"),
            kendoSlider: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.slider.min.js"),
            kendoDrawing: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.drawing.min.js"),
            kendoUpload: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.upload.min.js"),
            kendoListBox: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.listbox.min.js"),
            kendoPanelBar: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.panelbar.min.js"),
            kendoPivotGrid: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.pivotgrid.min.js"),
            kendocolorpicker: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.colorpicker.min.js"),
            pivotFieldMenu: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.pivot.fieldmenu.min.js"),
            kendoPivotConfigurator: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.pivot.configurator.min.js"),
            commonClientLogic: path.join(__dirname, "src/Client_Logics/" + client_setting + "/Common.js"),
            clientLogo: path.join(__dirname, "src/Client_Logics/" + client_setting + "/Assets/logo.png"),
            olCss: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/ol/ol.css'),
            kendocolorpicker: path.join(__dirname, "node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/js/kendo.colorpicker.min.js")
            
        }
    }
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ticman-ui",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
    "@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-animation": "^3.18.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-buttons": "^4.14.1",
    "@progress/kendo-react-common": "^5.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-conversational-ui": "^4.9.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dateinputs": "^5.5.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^5.3.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-intl": "^4.8.0",
    "@progress/kendo-react-treeview": "^3.18.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2019.3.1114",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "axios-retry": "^3.1.9",
    "big-integer": "^1.6.48",
    "blueimp-file-upload": "^9.30.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bootbox": "^5.5.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.4.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.7",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
    "esdoc-ecmascript-proposal-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "esdoc-jsx-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "esdoc-react-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "eslint-detailed-reporter": "^0.8.0",
    "extract-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "file-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "gridstack": "^7.2.3",
    "hijri-converter": "^1.1.1",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-link-type-plugin": "^1.0.4",
    "i18next": "^19.8.4",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.0.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.22",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jquery-slimscroll": "^1.3.8",
    "jquery.ui.widget": "^1.10.3",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "jspdf-html2canvas": "^1.4.9",
    "load-js": "^3.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-http-proxy-json": "^0.1.9",
    "npm": "^6.14.11",
    "ol": "^6.15.1",
    "ol-ext": "^4.0.10",
    "postal-codes-js": "^2.5.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dnd": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^16.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dropdown-tree-select": "^2.5.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-gtm-module": "^2.0.11",
    "react-i18next": "^11.8.5",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "^4.5.2",
    "react-joyride": "^2.3.1",
    "react-json-to-table": "^0.1.7",
    "react-orgchart": "^1.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "react-redux-toastr": "^7.6.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-select": "^2.4.1",
    "react-simple-treeview": "^1.0.4",
    "react-tag-input": "^6.8.0",
    "react-toastify": "^5.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "save": "^2.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.1",
    "tree-select": "^1.4.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "websocket": "^1.0.34",
    "xlsx": "^0.17.1",
    "xregexp": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.13",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.10",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "esdoc": "^1.1.0",
    "esdoc-ecmascript-proposal-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "esdoc-standard-plugin": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-detailed-reporter": "^0.8.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.1",
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "10.2.5",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.6",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.6.2",
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.3",
    "webpack": "^5.85.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.4.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.0"
  }
}
```

There is nothing important in my `App.js` for now.

When I run `npm start`, it throws error:

```
> ticman-ui@1.0.0 start
> webpack serve --config config/webpack.dev.js

[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/rajbelwal/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/config/webpack.dev.js' config
- /home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/config/webpack.dev.js
- /home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:119:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/config/webpack.dev.js:3:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/config/webpack.dev.js',
    '/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/home/Desktop/projects/ticman-ui/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

I have checked the path which is showing in requireStack, the path is correct.

Then what could be the reason it's not able to find the module and why not able to load webpack.dev.js, Any idea??

I have been stuck on this for 2 days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them! The error tells you the line it's coming from. Assuming no other lines in your config file, `require("./../NodeJsApi/config");`is failing. Does that file and folder exist? Does it have a file extension? Is the capitalization the same as your require statement?

Comment: It looks to me from the error log like the load is failing due to an error on line 3 of `webpack.dev.js`.  Have you checked to make sure the `require("./../NodeJsApi/config")` you're commenting to ignore is all good?

Comment: @AndyRay I did add `NodeJsApi` folder (containing "config" file) to the project. But the rest of the error remains the same. It's not able to load `webpack.dev.js`.

Comment: You'd better provide a minimal runnable demo, for example on `codesandbox`. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try running the `tree -L 2 -I "node_modules"` command on your terminal.

Comment: @xgqfrms  I have update the file structure what file do you need to see ?

Comment: It seems you are still ignoring some folders and files with the `tree` command output.

Comment: I'm sorry, but those were the only files. It's correct. Can you elaborate what exactly you're expecting there ?

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your `webpack.dev.js` config file

1. relative path error

```js
// const APP_CONFIG = require("./../NodeJsApi/config");
const APP_CONFIG = require("../NodeJsApi/config");
```

2. webpack entry file error

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        // main: "./src/main.js",
        main: "./src/index.js"
    },
}
```

Comment: I see, It removed some of the errors. Rest remains the same!

Comment: So, you need to provide a minimal runnable demo to help reproduce your problem. please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: such as a GitHub repo or a codesanbox project.